# чтение настроек из при запуске приложения (java)

Tags: java, maven, jar, настройки, properties

Добрый день,
есть задача, читать значения настроек при запуске программы... не понимаю как это реализовать (java)...
вот приложение:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties myProp = new Properties();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/my.properties");
            myProp.load(is);

            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(myProp.getProperty("outPath")+"text_out.txt");
            fileWriter.write(myProp.getProperty("text"));

            is.close();
            fileWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Fiel text_out.txt created");

            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

суть такая, есть некий файл *my.properties* в нем храниться 2 строчки, первая это текст, вторая путь к файлу в который этот текст необходимо поместить:

```
text    = Привет! как дела!
outPath = /Users/myMac/Downloads/rrr/
```

струтктура проекта такая (собирается maven):

```
main
  java
    MainClass
  resources
    my.properties
```

создаю при помощи maven(package) executable jar файл, запускаю всё работает, но всегда выводиться один и тот же текст и создается файл в одном и том же месте...

причем перемещаю jar файл куда угодно, он всегда работает...

насколько я понимаю, *my.properties* упаковывается в jar файл, и оттуда читается инфа...

Внимание вопрос, как писать программу так, чтобы программа читала данные из (допустим) рядом лежащего файла, и при изменении информации в этом файле она на эти изменения реагировала???

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте путь к `my.properties` в качестве параметра или пробуйте читать файл по относительному пути, тогда важно будет какая рабочая папка.

Чтобы следить за изменениями можно создать поток, который периодически будет проверять дату модификации файла и перечитывать его. Проще сделать `Timer` и запустить переодически `TimerTask`.

**Обновление**

Второй вариант, просто имя файла укажите, тогда он из текущей рабочей папки будет браться:

```
myProp.load(new FileInputStream("my.properties"));
```

Comment: неужели передача в качестве параметра файла с настройками это единственный вариат?... хотелось бы просто кликнуть 2 раза на executable jar не запуская его с параметрами через командную строку...

Answer (score 2):

я сделал так:

```
FileInputStream is = null;
...
is = new FileInputStream("my.properties");
```

сделал jar-ник, и просто рядом с ним положил файл *my.properties* теперь все работает именно так как мне надо.